# What is the dormant common ground between harmonic mechanical oscilators and electromagnetical ones?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, harmonic-oscillator

When I learnt electromagnetic oscillators I couldn't help but notice that it has many common stuff with mechanical ones. I know that it had to have sinusoidal equations. I (firstly, without simplifications) learnt $$q=Q \sin(\omega t+\phi_0)$$ which looks similar to  $$x=X\sin(\omega t+\phi_0)$$

I also know that these are derived by solving two similar D.E.s respectively. All the conclusions and derivations of additional quantities we have for electromagnetic oscillators seem to imply $$x\ \text{and its derivatives}\ \to q\ \text{and its derivatives},\ \  m \omega^2 \to\frac{1}{C}, m \to L$$ But are they really connected? Is there any reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

They are absolutely connected. In both cases, you have the following components:

- an "inertial term": this can be mass, or inductance. Something that resists change (in velocity, in current)
- a "linear force term": the spring ($F=-kx$) or the capacitor ($V=Q/C$).
- a "displacement term": this is $x$ for mechanical, and $Q$ for electrical. Their derivatives $v$ and $I$ are the thing being resisted by the inertial term above.

So there is a deep similarity, and the equations are going to look the same. You can go even further and add a drag term proportional to velocity (viscosity) or current (resistance) which shows that even as a damped harmonic oscillator, the two systems are analogous.

Comment: Are there any other systems that follow these principles?

Comment: I thought about this - but all the examples I come up with fundamentally reduce to one of these. I suppose you might argue that any kind of orbital motion is its own special case of a harmonic oscillator (if you look at the X component of restoring force for a circular orbit you can see it is proportional to the X displacement).

Comment: I though orbits aren't harminic oscillations because they don't start from a point A after, go to point A after $\frac{T}{2}$ and have opposite direction.

Comment: The X component of the circular orbit _looks_ just like harmonic motion... that's why I used the words "I suppose you could argue". I'm not going to push the point.